# Launching a bat file using CreateProcess windows API

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have written a bat file that works fine when launched from command prompt. Now I have written a small C++ program using `CreateProcess' to  launch the bat file from a C++ program. The C++ program take 2 command line parameters. One is the path of the bat file to be executed and the otherone is a path to a file where the output of bat file will be written. I am launching the process as below

```
   DWORD processflags =
        CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE
        //| CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
        | CREATE_NO_WINDOW
        ;


//security attribute
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttr;
    securityAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
        securityAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
        securityAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    HANDLE fileHandleforChildProcessTowrite,fileHandleforChildProcessToRead, fileHandleforChildProcessToErr 

     fileHandleforChildProcessTowrite = CreateFile(logfilepath, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, &securityAttr, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

  //STARTUP INFO
    STARTUPINFO sinfo;
    ZeroMemory(&sinfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
        sinfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
        sinfo.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
        sinfo.hStdOutput = fileHandleforChildProcessTowrite;
        sinfo.hStdInput = fileHandleforChildProcessToRead;

        sinfo.hStdError = fileHandleforChildProcessToErr;

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
            command,        // bat file to be run
            &securityAttr,            
            NULL,          
            TRUE,          // Set handle inheritance to TRUE/FALSE
            processflags,              // No creation flags
            NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
            NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
            &sinfo,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
            &pifo)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
            )
        {
            printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
            return PROCESS_CREATION_FAILED;
        }


  

    // Wait until child process exits.
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

//Rest of the code follows to clean up logic to close process and file handles
```

The problem I face here is that when I createProcess with bInheritHandles parameter set to FALSE batch file executes fine but no bat file out output will be written to the file handle which is expected but when I set bInheritHandles parameter to TRUE bat file execution fails and I get the below warning message in the log

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Can someone help me with this? why does bat file execution fails  with bInheritHandles set to TRUE but works fine if that flag is false? I cannot share complete bat file for obvious reasons please excuse me for that.

Comment: I assume you initialize `fileHandleforChildProcessToRead` and `hChildErr` as well, and that you just omitted it in your [mre]?

Comment: yes i have omiitted that part to reduce the source code in the question. As I mentioned in the question issue happens only with that flag set to TRUE

Comment: Have you checked that your `CreateFile` calls actually succeeds? All three of them?

Comment: Yes FILE HANDLE checks are done.

Comment: issue is with file handle flag dwShareMode of CreateFile API.  I used the  value FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE for that parameter and the issue is solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE`  for `dwShareMode` parameter of `CreateFile` API for file handles solves the problem

```
CreateFile(filehandlepate, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, &secureAttr, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```